# decode single base64 lines from an XML document with xml SLuper

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I am trying to decode an XML document that has lines that are base64 encoded.

For this I first tried to read the XML document with XML Slurper and then convert it line by line and write all lines into a string. Unfortunately I didn't manage to iterate over the single elements.

Because the base64 lines always have a "==" at the end, I tried after I had all lines one after the other in a big string, to read the elements in a List. however, I get then again only a big string out and can not edit the elements again individually.

The document looks like this:

```
<root>
<item>
    <LINE>base64encoded==</LINE>
</item>
<item>
    <LINE>base64encoded==</LINE>
</item>
<item>
    <LINE>base64encoded==</LINE>
</item>
<item>
    <LINE>base64encoded==</LINE>
</item>
<item>
    <LINE>base64encoded==</LINE>
</item>
</root>
```

thats my code

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)

def authorResult = root.item.LINE as String

List<String> items = Arrays.asList(authorResult.split("\\s=="));
```

and

```
root.each { thing ->
  println "LINE index: ${LINE.@indexNum}"
  
  }
}
```

But with noi luck, im stuck. Why both of my approaches didnt work? Pleas explain me what im doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
String s =""
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)

def titles = root.'**'.findAll { node -> node.name() == 'LINE' }*.text()

for(def i = 0; i<titles.size();i++) {
    Helpdecode = titles.get(i).toString()
    def Help2 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Helpdecode);
    String s2 = new String(Help2)
    s = s+s2
}
```

This code works perfectly on my machine. The code was transfered to a cloud and now im getting this error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException
```